# What is the easy way to set spacing between items in StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stackpanel

Is there an easy way to set default space between items inside StackPanel so I'll don't have to set Margin property on each item?

Comment: I would say Margin is the easiest way to go here... are they typically items of the same type? You can use implicit styles to set the Margin for each item...

Comment: Maybe I can use styles to set Margin for some base type? 'Control' for example

Comment: Also see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932510/how-do-i-space-out-the-child-elements-of-a-stackpanel

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if all the controls are the same then do as IanR suggested and implement a Style that catches that control. if it's not then you can't create a default style to a base class because it just won't work.

the best way for situations like these is to use a very neat trick - attached properties (aka Behaviors in WPF4)

you can create a class that has an attached property, like so:

```
public class MarginSetter
{
    public static Thickness GetMargin(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Thickness)obj.GetValue(MarginProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMargin(DependencyObject obj, Thickness value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MarginProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Margin.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MarginProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Margin", typeof(Thickness), typeof(MarginSetter), new UIPropertyMetadata(new Thickness(), CreateThicknesForChildren));

    public static void CreateThicknesForChildren(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var panel = sender as Panel;

        if (panel == null) return;

        foreach (var child in panel.Children)
        {
            var fe = child as FrameworkElement;

            if (fe == null) continue;

            fe.Margin = MarginSetter.GetMargin(panel);
        }
    }


}
```

now, to use it, all you need to do is to attach this attached property to any panel you want, like so:

```
<StackPanel local:MarginSetter.Margin="10">
    <Button Content="hello " />
    <Button Content="hello " />
    <Button Content="hello " />
    <Button Content="hello " />
</StackPanel>
```

Completely reusable of course.

Comment: The only problem is that it works statically: if you were adding/removing children once the panel has been instantiated, that won't work.

Comment: Your attached behavior could maybe subscribe to `LayoutUpdated`, and set the correct margin for new items as needed.

Comment: +1 for a great solution.  I think I'll be able to use that tomorrow!

Comment: @Mario - you're right, but i basically gave the general direction. Jens's idea would be a good way to continue - it's easy to solve the general case.

Comment: At runtime CreateThicknesForChildren event is invoked befora any children are added. How to fix this code so it'll work not only on designer?

Comment: register to one of the events of the panel that would happen after the children has already been added. i'm guessing Loaded might do the trick.

Comment: How conveniently cumbersome is WPF in comparison to HTML and CSS (LESS, SASS) when it comes to markup.

Comment: This is not going to work (any longer) and - for the children of the panel to be loaded - I have to subscribe the following event

    `private void StackPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MarginSetter.CreateThicknesForChildren(sender, new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs());
    }` otherwise at the attached property initialization the `panel.Children` has zero count and the foreach of `CreateThicknesForChildren` is skipped

Answer (score 52):

I use a transparent separator, which works well:

```
<Separator Opacity="0" Height="20"/>
```

You can of course use margins but then if you want to change the margins you have to update all of the elements.

The separator can even be styled in a static resource.

An attached property could do it too but I think it's overkill.

Comment: @Microsoft, too bad this is not supported on UWP... :'(

Comment: How do I use this? Do I have to manual add a `Seperator` element after each child element? I don't see how this is better than setting the `Margin` property directly each child item. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

```
<Rectangle Width="3"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

I find that creating a grid inside the stack panel, then adding the desired number of columns (or rows) as follows:

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="34" Width="698" Margin="10,5,10,10" Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <Grid Width="698" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="StartButton" Content="Start" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource 3DButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="70" Click="StartButton_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="HelpButton"  Content="Help"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource 3DButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="70" Click="HelpButton_Click"  />
            <Button x:Name="ExitButton"  Content="Exit"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource 3DButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="70" Click="ExitButton_Click" Foreground="Red" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: You could just omit the stackpanel and get the same effect. The Grid will stretch to its parent by default, by the way. Giving it a fixed width is unnecessary, and so a bad idea, as the parent may be resized later. WPF layouts use a lot of auto-sizing and stretching to parents.

Answer (score -2):

The accepted answer doesn't work anymore. But I used that answer and the blog the author of that answer (Elad Katz) to make a working code (tested in .Net Core) that I reproduce here:

```
    public static class EstablecedorMargen { 


    public static Thickness GetMargen(DependencyObject objeto) => objeto != null ? (Thickness)objeto.GetValue(PropiedadMargen) : new Thickness();

    public static void SetMargen(DependencyObject objeto, Thickness value) => objeto?.SetValue(PropiedadMargen, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropiedadMargen 
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Margen", typeof(Thickness), typeof(EstablecedorMargen), new UIPropertyMetadata(new Thickness(), Cambió));


    public static void Cambió(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (!(sender is Panel panel)) return;
        panel.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(EstablecerMargenControlesHijos);
    } 


    public static void EstablecerMargenControlesHijos(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        if (!(sender is Panel panel)) return;
        foreach (var hijo in panel.Children) {
            if (!(hijo is FrameworkElement feHijo)) continue;
            feHijo.Margin = GetMargen(panel);
        }

    } 


}
```

Then you use:

```
   <StackPanel local:EstablecedorMargen.Margen="10" >          
            <Button Content="1" />
            <Button Content="2" />
            <Button Content="3" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Leaving some English code would be much appreciated, that way people can follow the code much more easily. This is an international community, not a Spanish one.