# WPF MVVM - Style is lost for items in TreeView

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview, styles

I just started WPF and I'm getting problem for stylling.
I have a style that I use for all `TextBlock` in the `UserControl`.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

It work great for the `TextBlock` in the first `StackPanel` but not for the `TextBlock` in the `TreeView`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}" Grid.Row="2">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dml:TestCase}" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <!--Task Template-->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dml:Task}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Is there a way to do it without setting style on each `TextBlock` in the `TreeView`?

Comment: Sorry I didnt realize the problem please check this link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.110).aspx
   for TreeViewItem you want to give style then you need to give style for TreeViewItem.

Comment: All I want is some margin between TextBlock who are in the same StackPanel

Comment: @felix I keeping my eye on you to see if you encounter issues I can help you with - so far people helped you faster - thanks for repairing my posts ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok that here we go,

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}" >
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" DataType="Hdtable1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="HDTEmplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Credits:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/932609/2470362
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3102188/2470362

Answer (score 1):

Just do it in your ItemTemplate:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```