# WPF Style BasedOn parent Style in current context

Tags: wpf, styles, basedon

Say, I have a default style for a `TextBox` 'TextBoxStyleBase'. 
I then define a `DataGrid` style which has an own `TextBox` style BasedOn that Base-style, defining another Border Color.

In some place inside a `DataGrid` I want to define another `TextBox` style but inherit from the one defined in `DataGrid` style.

Is there a way to make a style inherit from the style that is currently defined for a specific control in the current 'context'?

EDIT:

To make it more clear, here's what I have:

```
<!-- explicit style for all TextBoxes -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="TextStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
</Style>

<!-- implicit style for all TextBoxes -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextStyle}"/>

<!-- DataGrid style changing inner TextBox style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextStyle}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        </Style>
        <!-- since TextBox has defined implicit style this would be equivalent to -->
        <!--<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        </Style>-->
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>

<Control>
    <DataGrid>
        <Row>
            <TextBox/> <!-- should show as defined in DataGrid style -->
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Row.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn=" ??? ">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Row.Resources>
            <TextBox/> <!-- should show with additional trigger -->
        </Row>
    </DataGrid>
</Control>
```

What to put in BasedOn = '???' so that the text shows up in FontSize 20 but Bold if hovered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot add two `Styles` with the same key inside the same `ResourceDictionary`. So if you already have defined an implicit `Style` without an `x:Key` in a `ResourceDictionary` for a specific type, you cannot add another one to the same `ResourceDictionary`.

Otherwise you should be able to base a `Style` on the default style that is in scope like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Style.Triggers>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following for the textbox inside the datagrid:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource <your style name>}">
```

PS:  would be TextBoxStyleBase in your case.

Comment: I suppose you understood my question wrong, please refer to my clearification

Comment: Why don't you give a key to it and use it wherever you need it?